# Batch code: between dates or greater/less than?

Tags: date, batch-file

I have a simple Batch script that does something on a certain date, but I want it to be able to perform this between dates, or always before or after a certain date.

```
@ECHO OFF

IF "%DATE%"=="12/12/2011" GOTO ARMREST
GOTO END

:ARMREST
ECHO HELLO WORLD!
PAUSE

:END
```

Now I tried using ">=" but it didn't work, I've been all over but can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I don't even know if that kind of complex boolean can be used? This is for Windows 7, very simple script, just wondering about the dates.

Also, I have a Spanish machine, of which the date value differs from the UK - so the UK's is "12/02/2011" (DD/MM/YYYY), while the Spanish one is 12/2/2011 (dd/m/yyyy) I think, but I can find that out with a simple @ECHO %DATE% can't I?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

%DATE% returns the current date using the short date format, that is fully (endlessly) customizable. One user may configure its system to return Fri040811, and another user may choose 08/04/2011...it's a complete nightmare for a BAT programmer.

A possible solution is to use WMIC. `WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day,Hour,Minute,Month,Second,Year /Format:table` returns the date in a convenient way to directly parse it with a FOR.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
   SET /A DAYS=%%F*10000+%%D*100+%%A
)
IF %DAYS% GTR 20111210 (
  IF %DAYS% LSS 20111230 (
    ECHO Yes!
  )
)
GOTO :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to normalize all dates with format yyyymmdd to be compared. For instance:

```
rem Convert from dd/m/yyyy to yyyymmdd
set date=%date:/=/0%
set year=%date:~-4,4%
set month=%date:~-8,2%
set day=%date:~0,2%
set normdate=%year%%month%%day%
```

Check for instance http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html for variable substring and replace.

Comparisons are done with lss, leq, gtr and geq.

Comment: I agree. I should have read "one of the machine where it must be run is Spanish".